# Showing truncated Poisson process has no unbiased estimator

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, parameter-estimation

> Suppose that $X$ has the Poisson distribution truncated on the right at $a$, so that it has the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $Y \leq a$, where $Y$ is distributed as $P(\lambda)$. Show that $\lambda$ does not have an unbiased estimator.

I'm trying to prove this using a proof by contradiction. Suppose $\delta(X)$ is an unbiased estimator for $g(\lambda) = \lambda$. Then:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \delta(k)\frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^k}{k!} 1_{k \leq a} = \lambda $$

Rearranging I get:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \delta(k)\frac{\lambda^{k-1}}{k!} 1_{k \leq a} = e^{\lambda}  $$

Is this a contradiction because the finite sum will never equal $e^\lambda$? Or do I need another argument?

Comment: You left out a normalizing factor.  The idea is that the resulting equation must hold for all values of $\lambda>0$.